# Why does Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper give me different results when run locally vs. running on server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, scheduled-tasks

I'm using [Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/) to get Scheduled Task information from a server. Here's my code, which I pretty much gathered from the documentation:

```
    public List<ScheduledTask> GetScheduledTasks()
    {
        using (TaskService ts = new TaskService("SERVERNAME", "userId", "domain", "password"))
        {
            foreach (var scheduledTask in ScheduledTasksToGet)
            {
                var task = ts.FindTask(scheduledTaskName);
                var taskScheduled = new ScheduledTask();
                taskScheduled.Name = task.Name;
                taskScheduled.LastRunTime = task.LastRunTime;
                taskScheduled.LastRunResult = task.LastTaskResult;
                scheduledTasks.Add(taskScheduled);
            }
        }
        return scheduledTasks;
    }
```

The server I'm trying to retrieve the tasks information from is a 2008 R2 server. I've confirmed that all of the tasks I'm looking to retrieve are in the root folder. This code works fine when I run it locally on my Windows 7 machine. However, when I deploy the application to our 2003 SP2 QA server, I'm unable to retrieve any tasks. I've also tried this piece of code:

```
    public List<ScheduledTask> GetScheduledTasks()
    {
        using (TaskService ts = new TaskService("SERVERNAME", "userId", "domain", "password"))
        {
            EnumerateFolderTasks(ts.RootFolder, tasks);
            foreach (var task in tasks)
            {
                if (ScheduledTasksToGet.Any(t => task.Name.StartsWith(t)))
                {
                    var scheduledTask = new ScheduledTask();
                    scheduledTask.Name = task.Name;
                    scheduledTask.LastRunTime = task.LastRunTime;
                    scheduledTask.LastRunResult = task.LastTaskResult;
                    scheduledTasks.Add(scheduledTask);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void EnumerateFolderTasks(TaskFolder folder, List<Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.Task> tasks)
    {
        foreach (Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler.Task task in folder.Tasks)
            tasks.Add(task);
        foreach (TaskFolder subFolder in folder.SubFolders)
            EnumerateFolderTasks(subFolder, tasks);
    }
```

Again, this piece of code runs fine locally, but on the server I only get one task returned when I'm expecting 10. I understand that there are differences between Task Scheduler 1 and Task Scheduler 2. I also read somewhere else on SO that some of the Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper methods may not be available for Task Scheduler version 1, or won't work as they do for version 2. I'm guessing that this is the reason for the difference in behavior. However, I've looked on the web and through the documentation and I'm having a hard time finding what method to get tasks will work for version 1.

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to move the application to a Windows 2008 server and the code works beautifully.